# Convert textbox value to another data type in Windows Store with C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, textbox, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Sorry for this question. I just got confused by the code to convert or parse value from textbox to int, float, double, etc in windows store. I'm a C# user and I tried this code

```
block1 = Convert.ToDouble(text1.Text); or block1 = double.Parse(text1.Text);
```

those method didn't work for me, does anybody can help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to easily select what type you want to covert the string to (int, double, float) you could make a simple method to convert the string.

Something like

```
private T ConvertTo<T>(string value) where T : IConvertible
{
    try
    {
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
string value = "33";

int intVal = ConvertTo<int>(value);
float floatVal = ConvertTo<float>(value);
double doubleVal = ConvertTo<double>(value);
```